# Unity - error CS0117: 'Score' does not contain a definition for 'score'

Tags: unity-game-engine

For the past couple of days I've been trying to make a simple flappy bird game. At the moment, I'm trying to write some code that will make the score go up every time the player passes through two pipes. I'm getting an error though, and I'm not too sure how to fix it. This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour {

    public static int score = 0;

    private void Start() {
        score = 0;
    }

    private void Update() {
        GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>().text = score.ToString();
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AddScore : MonoBehaviour {

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D collision) {
        Score.score++; // This is the line that's giving me errors
    }
}
```

The exact error I'm getting is - error CS0117: 'Score' does not contain a definition for 'score'. The reason I'm a bit confused is because on Vistual Studio Code it doesn't actually show any errors. The error only appears when I try to run the game.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [`CS0117`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0117) is a **compile time** error => `The error only appears when I try to run the game.` I doubt that ...

Answer (score 0):

```
error CS0117
```

In simple words, it occurs when you are trying to make a reference to a member that does not exist for the data type.

In order to fix it remove the references that you are trying to make which is not defined in the base class or look inside the definition of a type to check if the member exists and use that member as a reference.

For a better understanding you can have a look at this documentation : https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/205886966-What-is-CS0117-

Also you can change the datatype from `int` to `float` for more accurate score. From `public static int score = 0;` to  `public static float score = 0f;`

Comment: Why would you want to use a `float` for a score which is anyway only incremented in full steps (`++`) and how would this address this question?